# Intercepting Statically Linked Dependencies of a Dynamically Linked Library

Tags: c, linux, mips

I'm trying to debug an API in use by a third party app.
The third party app has a configuration I had thought impossible:

The application binary contains exports required by one of its shared library dependencies. That is, they dynamically linked their dependency, but that dependency's dependency is statically linked.

This is occurring on a MIPS based linux with an ancient kernel.

I have confirmed this using Ghidra to disassemble the executable/shared library.

Basically we have the binary and the shared object

```
file initApp
initApp: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, stripped

file libhyCoreSdk.so
libhyCoreSdk.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

objdump -T libhyCoreSdk.so | grep -i IMP_ISP_Open
00047900      DF *UND*  00000000 IMP_ISP_Open
```

initApp calls "coreAvInit" in libhyCoreSdk.so, and then libhyCoreSdk.so calls IMP_ISP_Open() back inside initApp.

You might be thinking "that's not that unusual, you can do that with callbacks, passing pointers, a call to dlsym etc. etc." But this isn't any of those things, this is a direct import/export of symbols exactly what you'd expect to see if libhyCoreSdk depended on another shared library.

All that aside, my real problem is that I am trying to figure out what parameters are being passed by IMP_ISP_Open and LD_PRELOAD does not help this strange/unique circumstance. I have another example application which is calling the same APIs against a shared library version of the API. When I use LD_PRELOAD (loading a little interceptor program I wrote) against that version it works great. But when I use it against this version that links back to the binary, it doesn't work.

I'm hoping someone has ideas on how I can intercept those API calls.

### Partial Solution:

Daniel Kleinstein has given me a good start. I renamed the target functions from IMP_... to XMP_... (e.g. IMP_ISP_DisableSensor-> XMP_ISP_DisableSensor). Now the IMP_ISP_DisableSensor from my LD_PRELOAD is correctly hit. Unfortunately, I'm still running into trouble. Calling dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "XMP_ISP_DisableSensor") returns NULL for no obvious reason... This means I can't redirect back to the original function.

Despite objdump showing this:

```
objdump -T initApp_mod | grep -i XMP
0061fb5c g    DF .text  00000338  Base        XMP_FrameSource_CreateChn
00613c6c g    DF .text  00000204  Base        XMP_ISP_DisableSensor
006097f0 g    DF .text  00000eb0  Base        XMP_Encoder_CreateChn
```

Comment: "but that dependency's dependency is statically linked." but `file libhyCoreSdk.so` shows that it's dynamically linked? What does `objdump -T libhyCoreSdk.so` show for `IMP_ISP_Open`'s import?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein I've added what it shows. Honestly it doesn't tell me much. Looking at the readelf output I can see IMP_ISP_Open is a dynamic symbol, but there's no entry for "initApp" in the .dynamic needed list. (Which makes sense, not sure how their could be)

Comment: Your shared library has an undefined symbol that is resolved by the executable rather than by any shared library listed as NEEDED in the dynamic section. There is nothing impossible or unusual (or indeed statically linked) here. (This is impossible in the world of Windows and DLLs, but shared libraries are not DLLs).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That does appear to be the case, and maybe my windows background is what made this seem so crazy. But that reality does nothing to solve my problems with LD_PRELOAD. Any thoughts on that? Why doesn't the LD_PRELOAD symbol take precedence over the one from the executable?

Comment: @wd40bomber27 `LD_PRELOAD` isn't working here because it doesn't take precedence over symbols exported by the main executable itself - just over symbols exported by shared libraries. I'm not sure what your case is exactly (binary research? Production code?), but in your case I might try patching the binary itself to rename the imported symbol (or easier, rename the main executable's exported symbol) to allow `LD_PRELOAD` hooking.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein ok that sounds like a reasonable approach. Unfortunately its not working. When I rename one of the target symbols (in this case IMP_ISP_DisableSensor) I just get this:

./initApp: can't resolve symbol 'IMP_ISP_DisableSensor'

Even though that symbol is provided by the library I've loaded with LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein ah sorry for the spam! That __did__ work. My real problem was I had messed up the linkage of the new method in the library  I was preloading. Fixed that and now it loads my version! Feel free to post that as an actual answer rather than a comment. (Or I will later today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic dependency is **not** statically linked against your main executable. When the dynamic dependency is loaded, a search is made for its import and is resolved by a symbol exported by the executable - indeed, the executable's symbols will always resolve before any of the other dynamic dependencies.

---

Unfortunately, this also prevents your usage of `LD_PRELOAD`.

`LD_PRELOAD` doesn't work because its injected library **does not** take precedence over symbols exported by the main executable itself - only over symbols exported by shared libraries.

---

If you wish to intercept the call using `LD_PRELOAD`, a crude but effective solution is to patch the main executable's exported symbol to a different name - this way it won't resolve when the dynamic dependency gets loaded, and your injected library can supply the symbol.

Comment: One additional problem I encountered was that no matter what I did I couldn't get the original (now renamed) symbol to resolve. No use of the DL APIs worked for some reason. This initially prevented me from redirecting to the original functions after my LD_PRELOAD'd symbol.


My fix for this was equally crude. My (MIPS LE running an ancient linux kernel) platform has zero ASLR. By looking up the symbols I was replacing using objdump I was able to substitute the dl call for the original offset directly. Thanks for your help!